# how to use settimeofday(2)?

Tags: c, linux, posix, glibc

What am I doing wrong here? I expect `settimeofday()` to change the system time, not return `EINVAL`.

```
$ uname -a
Linux io 4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 1 03:18:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat settimeofday.c 
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct timeval tv = {0, 0};
    if (settimeofday(&tv, 0) == -1)
        perror("settimeofday");
}
$ gcc settimeofday.c 
$ sudo ./a.out 
settimeofday: Invalid argument
```

The error is coming from a Thinkpad T450 running Fedora 23. The same code runs fine on OS X.

**EDIT**

To clarify, the command is being executed as root:

```
# whoami
root
# sudo ./a.out 
settimeofday: Invalid argument
```

As expected, I get EPERM not EINVAL if I run the program as a regular user:

```
$ ./a.out 
settimeofday: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Note that you need permission to `settimeofday`, not that it should return an `EINVAL` error if you're not running as root.

Comment: you should be sudo user or root user, by default its not allowed for normal user to change the time

Comment: See the "sudo" in "sudo ./a.out". The command is being run as root.

Comment: with same code  for me it worked perfectly fine

Comment: On some systems, under certain security settings, even the superuser can not set the time backwards with `settimeofday()` -- is this something Fedora does?

Comment: No. The call fails with EINVAL no matter what the timeval is set to, even if would cause time to jump forward. Anyways, if this was a security issue then I would expect EPERM.

Comment: You don't have a Linux Security Module installed that hooks into the settime syscall do you?

Comment: So I was wrong when I commented earlier and said that the call fails no matter what the timeval is set to. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commit [e1d7ba](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/e1d7ba8735551ed79c7a0463a042353574b96da3) was introduced to the Linux kernel in mid-2015 and restricts the value of the tv_sec field. The restriction is influenced by system uptime -- see the commit message and related LKML discussion for details.

That's what was causing the `settimeofday` call to return `EINVAL` and explains why the code runs on OS X and older Linux machines.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the manpage of settimeofday().

> If either tv or tz is NULL, the corresponding structure is not set or returned.

Comment: And a few lines further down it says:  `The  use of the timezone structure is obsolete; the tz argument should normally be specified as NULL.`

Comment: @John Hascall, After fully read the manpage of setimeofday(), it seems that the tz_dsttime fied of timezone will not be supported in linux, but the tz_minuteswest filed is still needed to be set. I am not sure I read correctly.

Comment: Numerous reputable examples (such as Robert Love's Linux System Programming) show settimeofday() used with the second argument set to NULL. Furthermore, I tried passing in a non-NULL timezone struct and it made no difference.

Comment: It seems you are prohibited to set tv to {0, 0}, the start of Epoch time. as mentioned in [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/High_002dResolution-Calendar.html), _Use adjtime (below) to make a smooth transition_ @JoshuaJohnson

Comment: The consequence of set tv to {0, 0}: http://www.wired.com/2016/02/dont-set-your-iphone-back-to-1970-no-matter-what/